# How can I speed up a det distance function in python with Numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

My 'arr_coordinates' stores the x and y coordinates in 2 different columns. The 'distance' function returns an array that contains all distances between the coordinates.

My code:

```
xlim = (0, 1800)
ylim = (0, 1800)
arr_x = ([])
arr_y = ([])
for i in range(300):
    arr_x = np.append(arr_x, random.randint(xlim[0], xlim[1]))
    arr_y = np.append(arr_y, random.randint(ylim[0], ylim[1]))
arr_coordinates = np.vstack((arr_x, arr_y)).T

@numba.jit(forceobj=True)
def distance(arr_coordinates):
    arr_distances = ([])
    for i in range(len(arr_coordinates)):
        coordinate = arr_coordinates[i]
        for j in range(len(arr_coordinates)):
            other_coordinate = arr_coordinates[j]
            distance = ((other_coordinate[0] - coordinate[0]) ** 2 + (other_coordinate[1] - coordinate[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5 #√[(x₂ - x₁)² + (y₂ - y₁)²]
            arr_distances = np.append(arr_distances, distance)
    return arr_distances

print("time", timeit.timeit(functools.partial(distance, arr_coordinates), number=1))
```

Without the Numba decorator it is faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, you should forget a function with the name `np.append` exists, this function is very slow, it's a thousand times slower than `list.append`, if it is possible to calculate the output size beforehand and reserve it at the beginning then you should definitely do it, which is currently your case.

```py
import numpy as np
import random
import numba
import timeit
import functools
from math import sqrt

xlim = (0, 1800)
ylim = (0, 1800)
arr_x = ([])
arr_y = ([])
for i in range(300):
    arr_x = np.append(arr_x, random.randint(xlim[0], xlim[1]))
    arr_y = np.append(arr_y, random.randint(ylim[0], ylim[1]))
arr_coordinates = np.vstack((arr_x, arr_y)).T

@numba.jit(forceobj=True)
def distance(arr_coordinates):
    arr_distances = ([])
    for i in range(len(arr_coordinates)):
        coordinate = arr_coordinates[i]
        for j in range(len(arr_coordinates)):
            other_coordinate = arr_coordinates[j]
            distance = ((other_coordinate[0] - coordinate[0]) ** 2 + (other_coordinate[1] - coordinate[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5 #√[(x₂ - x₁)² + (y₂ - y₁)²]
            arr_distances = np.append(arr_distances, distance)
    return arr_distances

@numba.njit
def distance_numba(arr_coordinates):
    arr_distances = np.empty((len(arr_coordinates),len(arr_coordinates)),dtype=arr_coordinates.dtype)
    for i in range(len(arr_coordinates)):
        coordinate = arr_coordinates[i]
        for j in range(len(arr_coordinates)):
            other_coordinate = arr_coordinates[j]
            distance = sqrt(((other_coordinate[0] - coordinate[0]) ** 2 + (other_coordinate[1] - coordinate[1]) ** 2)) #√[(x₂ - x₁)² + (y₂ - y₁)²]
            arr_distances[i,j] = distance
    return arr_distances

functools.partial(distance, arr_coordinates)()  # never time the first call
functools.partial(distance_numba, arr_coordinates)()  # never time the first call
print("time", timeit.timeit(functools.partial(distance, arr_coordinates),number = 1))
print("time", timeit.timeit(functools.partial(distance_numba, arr_coordinates), number= 1))
```

```
time 2.0872249000000003
time 0.0002234000000003178
```

and there is a 10,000 speedup just because we no longer use `np.append`, and actually reserving the memory beforehand.

a small note, using `sqrt` is also faster than `**0.5` because computer has special hardware that does `sqrt` faster than the hardware that does `pow`.

as for `**2` the compiler will correctly resolve it to `x*x` instead of calling `pow` so it doesn't need to be hand-unrolled.